# Word meaning appearance of a word on a page? (emboldened, italicised etc.)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm sure there's a word referring to the appearance of a written word, such as its font face, whether it's emboldened or not and so on.

I can't remember what it is - can anyone help?

Edit: Some of the responses are only appropriate for printed or typed words. They're close, but not quite what I'm looking for

Comment: You say you're looking for a word that "describes written text too", yet your question asks for a word that covers characteristics such as *font face* & *emboldening*, whereas standard written words (except for calligraphy) does not have such characteristics. So what are you asking for?

Comment: If I leave a hand-written note in which some words are underlined while others are in small caps, is that not a form of text decoration?

Answer (score 7):

***Typography***

art and technique of arranging type in order to make language visible (wikipedia)

Comment: Close - but what I'm thinking of doesn't necessarily relate to printed text; it describes written text too. I'll have a look through the Wikipedia article though, it could lead me to it

Comment: @jackweirdy: You might be interested in [orthography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthography), since that includes handwriting as well as printed and other mechanically / electronically produced text. But so far as I know, ***orthograph*** itself is just a rare archaic word for [an instance of] handwriting.

Comment: Typography can refer to written text also. Have a read here: http://letterror.com/noordzij/meaning/  "lexicographic moralism, an attempt to reduce the scope of a word to the meaning it has in an entirely different context"

Answer (score 2):

The appearance of a font is its ***style***.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font):

> Each **style** may still be in a separate "font file"—for instance, the typeface "Bulmer" may include the fonts "Bulmer roman", "Bulmer italic", "Bulmer bold" and "Bulmer extended"...

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS/Properties/font-style):

> The `font-style` property selects between normal, italic and oblique faces within a font family.

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for is: [***typeface***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface)

> Each font of a typeface has a specific weight, style, condensation,
> width, slant, italicization, ornamentation, and designer or foundry
> (and formerly size, in metal fonts) [...] There are thousands of [**different typefaces**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces) in existence, with new ones being developed constantly.
>
> The art and craft of designing typefaces is called type design. [...]The distinction between font and typeface is that a font designates a specific member of a type family such as roman, boldface, or italic type, while **typeface designates a consistent visual appearance or style** which can be a "family" or related set of fonts. For example, a given typeface such as Arial may **include roman, bold, and italic fonts**.

Answer (score 0):

In the Web design realm (mine), the CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) specification uses **font-style** to refer to slant or inclination and **font-weight** to refer to boldness/lightness.